# Extjs4 How to decode a json code with a json string inside?

Tags: json, extjs

I want to decode in extjs4 with Ext.decode(string), a json string with json string inside, just like this:

```
var string = "{success:true, 
rows:[{"jsonfields":"[
{\\"name\\":\\"cm:title\\",\\"title\\":\\"Titolo\\",\\"description\\":\\"Titolo del contenuto\\",\\"dataType\\":\\"d:mltext\\",\\"url\\":\\"\/api\/property\/cm_title\\"},
{\\"name\\":\\"cm:content\\",\\"title\\":\\"Contenuto\\",\\"description\\":\\"Contenuto\\",\\"dataType\\":\\"d:content\\",\\"url\\":\\"\/api\/property\/cm_content\\"},
{\\"name\\":\\"cm:name\\",\\"title\\":\\"Nome\\",\\"description\\":\\"Nome\\",\\"dataType\\":\\"d:text\\",\\"url\\":\\"\/api\/property\/cm_name\\"}]"}
]}";
```

As you can see "jsonfields" is a json string code.
How I can decode this string with Ext.decode(string)
Any suggests?

Comment: You keys must be quoted (`\"success\":`, `\"rows\":`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with your JSON code.

1. All of your keys needed to be in quotes (success and rows were not).
2. Use single quotes when embedding a JSON string directly into javascript. This way you can avoid using the escape character.

Below is the correct JSON code. I have also updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4QEP/6/) link.

```
var string = '{
"success": true,
"rows": [
    {
        "jsonfields": [
            {
                "name": "cm: title",
                "title": "Titolo",
                "description": "Titolodelcontenuto",
                "dataType": "d: mltext",
                "url": "/api/property/cm_title"
            },
            {
                "name": "cm: content",
                "title": "Contenuto",
                "description": "Contenuto",
                "dataType": "d: content",
                "url": "/api/property/cm_content"
            },
            {
                "name": "cm: name",
                "title": "Nome",
                "description": "Nome",
                "dataType": "d: text",
                "url": "/api/property/cm_name"
            }
        ]
    }
]}';


var decodedString = Ext.decode(string);
console.log(decodedString);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct way to decode JSON with Ext and the exception is likely telling you about some invalid syntax in your JSON string.  The [JSON format](http://www.json.org/) is very strict.

You can use an online validator like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to help figure out what's wrong with your syntax.

One other note: in cases like this, it's usually easier to use single quotes around your string so that you can embed double-quotes without having to escape them.

```
var string = '{ "success": true, ...}'
```